# scrbook: chapters open on any page, but parts open on odd pages followed by a blank page

Tags: sectioning, scrbook

I am writing a book using the `scrbook` class. My publisher is asking for:

1. chapters open on any page, and are *not* followed or preceded by a blank page.
2. parts open on odd pages, and are always followed by a blank page.

I am aware of the `openany`, `openright`, `openleft` Koma options, but these seem to apply to chapters and parts simultaneously, whereas I need these two heading types to behave differently.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Here's a MWE:

```latex
﻿\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{part 1}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 2}
\lipsum[2]

\part{part 2}
\chapter{chapter 3}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 4}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple solution. But if  a chapter follows a part it will be preceded by a blank page.

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{part 1}
\cleardoublepage %<<<<

\chapter{chapter 1}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 2}
\lipsum[2]

\part{part 2}
\cleardoublepage %<<<<<

\chapter{chapter 3}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 4}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The rules can not be applied at the same time also in this case

```
    \documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{part 1}   
\cleardoubleoddpage

\chapter{chapter 1}
\lipsum[2]
%   \chapter{chapter 2}
%   \lipsum[2]

\part{part 2}
\cleardoubleevenpage % <<<<

\chapter{chapter 3}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 4}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Part 2 now starts in an even page. Perhaps you should recheck the rules with the publisher or look for allowed exceptions.

[image: output2]

With a `partx` command it seems to work. provided that the rule for chapters does not apply to the first chapter after a part nor the last, before a new part.

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\partx}[1]{\cleardoubleoddpage\part{#1}\cleardoubleoddpage}


\begin{document}

\partx{part 1}

\chapter{chapter 1}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 2}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 3}
\lipsum[2]

\partx{part 2}
\chapter{chapter 4}
\lipsum[2]

\partx{part 3}

\chapter{chapter 5}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{chapter 6}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: output3]

Comment: Thanks for illustrating the corner cases. It looks like \cleardoubleoddpage will get me most of the way there, and I now know what clarification to ask from the publisher. Very nice and complete answer!

Comment: @Vincent Thank you! I just added a last picture I forgot. But it seems you do not need It.